# Animate textBox from left to right and repeat

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I started to play around with animations in wpf, i am trying the following:

```
My Title 
 My Title 
e  My Titl 
le My Tit
tle My Ti
```

I mean that the title would move from left to write.

[image]

For now I have:

```
 <TextBlock  Name="MyWipedText"                                             
                Width="80"
                FontSize="35"
                Foreground="White"                                      
                Text="My Title"  >                

        <TextBlock.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="MyWipedText"                           
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Width)"
       To="0.0" Duration="0:0:4"                               
        AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </TextBlock.Triggers>
    </TextBlock>
```

[Related link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-apply-animations-to-text)

Comment: There is no built-in animation that can do this. If you do not want to create a custom control, just use a DispatcherTimer to cyclically change the displayed text.

Comment: @Clemens can you please add a code snippet as answer

Answer (score 0):

With a TextBlock like

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="Hello, World. "/>
```

you can easily animate the text with a DispatcherTimer:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1) };
    timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        var text = textBlock.Text;
        var last = text.Length - 1;
        textBlock.Text = text.Substring(last, 1) + text.Substring(0, last);
    };
    timer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Do you think that Is there a way to achive that using xaml? because now with C# it looks disrupted because the timer tick, in xaml it uselly looks smoother

Comment: You can't create the Tick handler of the DispatcherTimer in XAML. For a smoother animation, you would (for example) need two horizontally stacked TextBlocks showing the same text, and animate their horizontal position, underneath an element that clips them.

Comment: @ Clemens Can ypu please add it to your answer? if it's not too copmplicate

Comment: You won't try *something* yourself?

Comment: @Clements That could take me a couple of days/ weeks because I'm new with xaml, if you can please save me those days, I'm learning from answers

Comment: What Clements is suggesting is similar to this marquee animation: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31416.wpf-mvvm-friendly-user-notification.aspx#Marquee

Comment: Obviously, your canvas would be smaller. As Clemens mentioned you would also need to make it clip.