# Animate Text from left to right and repeat without whitespace?

Tags: c#, wpf

There should not be any blank space between the first loop animation and the next loop.

The animation is that name1 should be right after name4, not with a big gap.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061105/animate-textbox-from-left-to-right-and-repeat) but don't know how to implement it in xaml.

Here is my code and running result graph.

Xaml:

```
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.X" From="0" To="-150"  RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                              
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Listboxchild" Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }

    }
    
    public class ViewModel
    {
        
        public ObservableCollection<Message> MessageCollection { get; set; } 
        public ViewModel()
        { 
            MessageCollection = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
            MessageCollection.Add (new Message() { MyName = "name1" });
            MessageCollection.Add (new Message() { MyName = "name2" });
            MessageCollection.Add (new Message() { MyName = "name3" });
            MessageCollection.Add (new Message() { MyName = "name4" });
        }
    
    }
    public class Message
    {
        public string MyName { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return MyName;
        }
    }
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using a ListBox instead of a simple ItemsControl? And why not just a single TextBlock?

Comment: Hi,@Clemens . I want to scroll every item in the collection. Can i achieve the above effect if I use TextBlock? Is there any documentation or code i can refer to ?

Comment: Hi,@Clemens . Can we do this using TextBlock or ItemsControl without considering the data?